# BURG installed, only GRUB2 loads

Tags: dual-boot, burg

I apologize if this question is found elsewhere, but I have already tried to find an answer and don't know where to look anymore. I am new to Ubuntu.

My issue is that I installed BURG following the instructions in [this tutorial](http://linuxmotion.com/tutorials/80-how-to-install-burg-in-ubuntu-12-10).

As you can see, instead of running the standard command

```
sudo burg-install "(hd0)"
```

the install location is selected during the installation. I just accepted the suggestion that was in the window.

Trying

```
sudo burg-emu
```

does bring up BURG, but if I reboot my system, GRUB2 comes up and not BURG. Given that GRUB2 works just fine, I am about to give up, but I would enjoy the aesthetics of BURG.

Comment: Could add the output of `df` and `sudo fdisk -l` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Burg have similar command line option with Grub. It should some thing like:

```
sudo burg-install /dev/sda
```

(I will update it if get more info)